# AppCompat v7 - NoClassDefFoundError ActionBarOverlayLayout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After spending almost an entire day trying to remove ABS and replace it with AppCompat, when I run it I get this error:

```
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): Process: com.gordon.status, PID: 3339
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gordon.status/main.Status}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:273)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at main.Status.onCreate(Status.java:64)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5586)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     ... 11 more
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     ... 22 more
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$1
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:91)
01-21 17:13:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     ... 25 more
```

Everything is extended from ActionBarActivity or Fragment, and appcompat-v7 added on as an Android library, with v4 and v7 jars inside of the referenced v7 library. I am not using getSupportActionBar() or getActionBar() anywhere in the code that is used when the app is first launched.

I'm using Eclipse with no Gradle. I have cleaned, rebuilt, and restarted Eclipse many times. What am I doing wrong? I'm slowly losing my mind :(

Comment: Post your styles.xml, activity/fragment layout files.

Comment: I'm using @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light. The main view is just a basic relativelayout  with a basic listview.